# Filtering fields from ActiveRecord/ActiveModel JSON output (by magic!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord, metaprogramming

I want to filter out specific fields from ActiveRecord/ActiveModel classes when outputting JSON.

The most straightforward way to do this is just overriding `as_json`, perhaps like so:

```
def as_json (options = nil)
  options ||= {}
  super(options.deep_merge({:except => filter_attributes}))
end

def filter_attributes
  [:password_digest, :some_attribute]
end
```

This works, but it's a little verbose and lends itself to not being DRY pretty fast. I thought it would be nice to just declare the filtered properties with a magical class method. For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FilterJson

  has_secure_password
  filter_json :password_digest
  #...
end

module FilterJson
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter_json (*attributes)
      (@filter_attributes ||= Set.new).merge(attributes.map(&:to_s))
    end

    def filter_attributes
      @filter_attributes
    end
  end

  def as_json (options = nil)
    options ||= {}
    super(options.deep_merge({:except => self.class.filter_attributes.to_a}))
  end
end
```

The problem with this is getting it to deal with inheritance properly. Let's say I subclass User:

```
class SecretiveUser < User
  filter_json :some_attribute, :another_attribute
  #...
end
```

Logically, it makes sense to filter out `:some_attribute`, `:another_attribute`, and also `:password_digest`.

However, this will only filter the attributes declared on the class. To the desired end, I tried to call `super` within `filter_attributes`, but that failed. I came up with this, and it's a hack.

```
def filter_attributes
  if superclass.respond_to?(:filter_attributes)
    superclass.filter_attributes + @filter_attributes
  else
    @filter_attributes
  end
end
```

This is obviously brittle and not idiomatic, but there's the "what" that I'm trying to accomplish.
Can anyone think of a way to do it more correctly (and hopefully more elegantly)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a **safer** solution to **white-list** attributes than to black-list them. This will prevent unwanted future attributes added to `User` or `SomeUser` from making it into your JSON response because you forgot to add said attributes to `filter_json`.

You seem to be looking for a solution to your specific inheritance issue. I'm still going to point out **[active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)**, as I feel it is a saner way to manage serialization.

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name
end

class SecretUserSerializer < UserSerializer
  attributes :secret_attribute, :another_attribute
end
```

Given some `SecretUser` `s` you can do

```
SecretUserSerializer.new(s).as_json
```

and you'll get `:id`, `:first_name`, `:last_name`, `:secret_attribute`, and `:another_attribute`. The inheritance works as expected.

Comment: Oh, I really like this actually. It's secure, elegant, and makes testing easier too. I might use this even if something relevant to what I was looking at surfaces. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted. This is a better solution than the one I wanted. Regarding the inheritance problem, do you know why it is that I can't call `super` in the class method anyway? Is it because it's defined as part of a module?